# How to re-synchronize the Prometheus time?

Tags: docker, prometheus

This morning I had a problem with Prometheus, it was -2 hours late. So I had error about time stamp and no data were synchronized.

So is there a way to re-sync the time of Prometheus ? (I did `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` but I don't want to do that every time)
https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/issues/9 --> it's the errors I had this morning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming this was previously working, then something messed up time on your machine. Run a NTPd to fix this.

Comment: Ok so I'll check that

Comment: If you're on ubuntu you can fix the time with: `sudo timedatectl set-ntp off` and `sudo timedatectl set-ntp on`